# Converting audio to text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudiorecorder

I would like to implement a project in which the recorded audio s converted into text.
I could do this using mturk where the recorded audio is uploaded and stored some where in cloud and the link is forwarded to the mturk but this would take longer time and it would be better if I could implement anything that does this task instantly and from iphone itself.
Is there any ways to do this ? DO i get some custom framework to work with voice so that it converts the audio into text.

Comment: This is a little broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by little broad ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is for solving specific problems, as explained by the text under the "closed as not constructive" banner under this question. It's hard to tell if you are looking for a library recommendation that fits a certain criteria, or general advice on how to go about your project. If you can fix that, I'd be glad to reopen this. Please, don't take it personally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is looking at something like
[OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

You can use that to do speech recognition and text to speech and has some instructions on how to implement with iPhone

Comment: any other suggestion  convert audio to text file  objective c

Comment: shabbirv sir please let me know how to convert audio to text